# Unique identifiers for each resource in RESTful API?

Tags: api, rest

In an ideal RESTful API that supports multiple accounts, should each resource have it's unique identifier across the entire system, or it is OK if that identifier is unique for the specific account that it belongs to.

Are there any **pros** and **cons** for each scenario?

To give an example.

Would this be fine from the REST principles?

```
http://api.example.com/account/1/users/1
...
http://api.example.com/account/50/users/1
```

or would this approach be recommended?

```
http://api.example.com/account/1/users/{UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER}
...
http://api.example.com/account/50/users/{ANOTHER_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reveal valid user numbers by always having the first user as 1.  Someone then knows that any account will also have a user 1.  I'm not saying that you should hide user IDs just through obscurity but why make it easy for someone to find the user IDs in another account?

Answer (score 2):

All that really matters is that each resource has a unique identifier. Both of your examples accomplish that, so you seem to be okay (RESTfully speaking)

I don't see any compelling reason to use one over the other. I'd choose whatever makes more sense for your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Since, from the perspective of an external system using your REST API, the entire address should be considered to be the "identifier" for that resource object, so your first example is fine.